# Is there a way to get HTML5 to alter text color based on negative or positive values?

Tags: c#, html

I really have no experience using HTML 5 and thought I would see if this is possible or not.

Anyway I could use HTML5 here to change the text color to red if the value is negative?

Trying to avoid using JavaScript or Jquery for now.

The output file of this code is going to an HTML file.

```
    vWriteFile.WriteLine("<tr>" + "<td>" + key + "</td>" + "<td>" + iSumOpen + "</td>" + "<td>" + iSumBuy + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + iSumSell + "</td>" + "<td>" + iSumSettleMM + "</td>" + "</tr>");
```

Here is the entire method:

```
    public void printToHTML(string vOutputPath)
    {
        StreamWriter vWriteFile = new StreamWriter(vOutputPath);
        vWriteFile.WriteLine("<table style=\"width:100%\">");
        vWriteFile.WriteLine("<tr>" + "<td>" + "<b>Account</b>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<b>Open</b>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<b>Buy</b>" + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + "<b>Sell</b>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<b>SettleMM</b>" + "</td>" + "</tr>");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<DataRecord>> kvp in vSummaryResults)
        {
            string key = kvp.Key; //assigns key
            List<DataRecord> list = kvp.Value;  //assigns value

            int iSumOpen = 0;
            int iSumBuy = 0;
            int iSumSell = 0;
            double iSumSettleMM = 0;

            foreach (DataRecord rec in list)
            {
                if (vSummaryResults.ContainsKey(key))
                {

                    iSumOpen += rec.open;
                    iSumBuy += rec.buy;
                    iSumSell += rec.sell;
                    iSumSettleMM += rec.settleMM;

                }

                else
                {
                    vSummaryResults.Add(key, list);
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(key + "\t" + iSumOpen + "\t" + iSumBuy + "\t" + iSumSell + "\t" + iSumSettleMM + "\t");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------");

            //vWriteFile.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", key, iSumOpen, iSumBuy, iSumSell, iSumSettleMM);
            vWriteFile.WriteLine("<tr>" + "<td>" + key + "</td>" + "<td>" + iSumOpen + "</td>" + "<td>" + iSumBuy + "</td>"
                + "<td>" + iSumSell + "</td>" + "<td>" + iSumSettleMM + "</td>" + "</tr>");
        }
        vWriteFile.WriteLine("</table>");
        vWriteFile.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Setting colors is really more of a CSS thing than something you would do directly in HTML. Since you're generating the markup from C# code, have you tried setting a CSS class based on the  value in question?

Comment: Do it in the method that you are showing us.  Break up your concatenation and put a `if` statement or use the ?/: operator.

Comment: @ThatBlairGuy that is what I am gonna end up using is CSS.  Was just curious because I didn't know HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: As Nathan K indicated in comments, you should use CSS classes. I think the best method is to use some kind of ternary statements:**

```
vWriteFile.WriteLine("<tr><td class=\"" + value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive" + "\">" + value + "</td></tr>");
```

**Older answer that might also work:**

You could use some conditions like:

```
if(value < 0) {
    vWriteFile.WriteLine("<tr><td style=\"background-color:red;\">" + value + "</td></tr>");
}
else {
    vWriteFile.WriteLine("<tr><td>" + value + "</td></tr>");
}
```

Comment: Even better might be to give it a class so the color and display can be controlled with a CSS file instead of having to rewrite the source here.